# How to write a factory for a method that belongs_to two different instance of the same model and requires its id's in Factory Bot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, factory-bot

I have a `User` model that `has_many` accounts, each `Account` `belongs_to` one user and `has_many` transactions, each `Transactions` to two different accounts (`sender_account` and `recipient_account`), the original `belongs_to` method that adds the factory (like `account`) will not work since I need a `sender_account` and `recipient_account`.

If I manually set the ID with `sender_account 1` and run `rpsec` I get:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:
       Account(#5570447856500) expected, got 1 which is an instance of Integer(#5570414320800)
```

Even when the ID's are stored as `Integer`.

How can I add an association when my model `belongs_to` to different instances of the same model?
I already have my Account and User factory defined and they work as expected.

Comment: Please show the code of the failing test and how you set up the associations in your models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:
       Account(#5570447856500) expected, got 1 which is an instance of Integer(#5570414320800)
```

Actually, this error says, that integer is specified instead of account, so we can specify existing account ids to `sender_account_id` and `recipient_account_id`:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :transaction do
    sender_account_id 1
    recipient_account_id 2
  end
end
```

Another solution is to specify the factory of the created association:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :transaction do
    association :sender_account, factory: :account
    association :recipient_account, factory: :account
  end
end
```

This will create an accounts for `sender_account` and `recipient_account` associations using `account` factory

Comment: The second solution works like a charm, thanks a lot @Igor Drozdov!